# Angular CSS ngAnimate translated to developer

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-animate, angular-transitions

`ngAnimate` when used with routings has different "CSS Styles" that can be set to produce different transitions.

**Is this the correct template that will cover all CSS Options for a transition?**

> *myAnimation* = represent my css template.

```
.myAnimation {}
.myAnimation.ng-enter {}
.myAnimation.ng-enter-active {}
.myAnimation.ng-leave {}
.myAnimation.ng-leave-active {}
```

**Is there any guide or documentation on what is being affect and when?**

I have been playing with those for a while and I still do not understand the role each of those CSS items and the role they play in the animation and I am referring to the "*despairing view*" and the "*new view"* . I understand this involves understanding CSS as well but what I am looking for is to understand this using the simplest CSS... something a developer could use to evolve from there.

Answer (score 6):

When it comes to Angular animations, [year of moo](http://www.yearofmoo.com/) is your best friend. This is the blog from the author of ngAnimate Matias Niemela.

I would start off with this post: [Remastered Animation in AngularJS 1.2](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html), but do check out his other posts like [Staggering Animations in AngularJS](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/12/staggering-animations-in-angularjs.html) and [others](http://www.yearofmoo.com/).

[Remastered Animation in AngularJS 1.2](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html) really covers 99% of what you need to know about animations in angular and provides explanations and examples on CSS Transitions, CSS Keyframe Animations, as well as JavaScript Animations for all the build-in Angular directive that supports animations out of the box: ngView, ngInclude, ngIf, ngSwitch, ngClass, ngShow, ngHide as well as how to apply it on your own custom directives.